# vim: how to get path to search up and down a directory tree

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get vim `gf` to work on include files. If the path is local, things work fine. But if it has to search up a directory tree and down a specified tree it cannot find the file.

What I want is easily demonstrated:

```
cd /some/src
mkdir -p a/long/path/down
mkdir -p a/long/path/again
touch a/long/path/down/util.h
echo '#include "a/long/path/down/util.h"' > a/long/path/again/file.cc
cd a/long/path/again
vim file.cc
```

In this example, when I compile I would use `-I/some/src` so that `a/long/path/down/util.h` would be found when file.cc is compiled.

Now, in the vim session for `file.cc` where I am in the `a/long/path/down/` directory (note the `cd` above), I do a `gf` on the `a/long/path/down/util.h` include path. What is the `path` specification I need to get this to work? I assumed that this would be all I need:

```
set path+=**
```

Yet I get:

```
E447: Can't find file "a/long/path/down/util.h" in path
```

Shouldn't `**` make it search up, up, up... for `a` then find that `a/long/path/down/util.h` is there?

In my project, I may have multiple versions of `src/` in `/some`, so I want the search to be relative from `pwd`. That is, `set path+=/some/src` is not a workable solution for me.

Thanks!

Comment: `**` is not about searching up and up... It's searching recursively down and down. For that specific case, `set path+=../../../../**` just works. But this is not commonly workable.

Comment: BTW, what does `/some` mean? Is it a directory in `/` or just a common directory like `some/`?

Comment: Thank you for the replies. `/some` is just a literal directory name I made up for this example, in this case an absolute path from `/`. I didn't realize that '**' didn't search up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `;`, not `**`.

```
set pah+=**;
```

does what you want but it will be pretty slow because Vim will go "up and down, recursively", then "up and down, recursively", etc. looking for your file in an incredibly large number of directories.

One possible improvement could be to use a "stop-directory":

```
set path+=**;/path/to/a/long/path
```

so that Vim doesn't search for your file in your whole hard drive. The closer the stop-directory is, the more useful `path` is.

A better improvement would be to add specific directories to `path`:

```
set path+=/path/to/a/long/path/down
```

which works very well with projects/frameworks/languages that mandate standard directory structures. This can be automated on a per-filetype or per-path basis.

Everything is pretty clearly explained under `:help file-searching` and `:help 'path'`.